# Google Streetview Wide Angle

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-street-view

I have a Streetview map on my own website, but its in wide angle perspective.
I'm watching a road and on the right is a slip road in a 90 degree angle.
You can't see this road on maps.google.com, but on my own streetview map, the road runs diagonally.

I'm using Google Maps JavaScript API v3

Is there a way I can disable the wide angle perspective?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried to reproduce the problem, but it has been solved.
I didn't do anything so it must be something with the Google API, although that seems very unlikely.

Thanks for all your interests.

Comment: Probably was, they often fix bugs without necessarily publishing it. Glad you got it working.

Answer (score 0):

For those who needs some clarification:

[image: Own website]

[image: Website from Google itself]

As you can see the first one, the small road seems to hit the main road in an angle, but this doesn't happen on the main road on Google Maps.

Answer (score 0):

Could it be that you’re using a different zoom level? Google’s [documentation on StreetView panorama zoom levels](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/streetview#TilingPanoramas) suggests that a zoom level of 0 leads to a 180º field of view, and that a zoom level of 1 leads to a 90º field of view; this seems to approximately match [Sietse’s answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12191971/google-streetview-wide-angle#answer-12192030).

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but I'm not using panorama view.